# Problems with devtools 2.3.2 package - package is not found

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

This is the output of the flutter pub cache repair command:

Failed to repair devtools 2.3.2. Error:
Pub failed to delete entry because it was in use by another process.
This may be caused by a virus scanner or having a file
in the directory open in another application.
Reinstalled 229 packages.
Failed to reinstall 1 package:

- devtools 2.3.2
  Reactivating devtools 2.3.2...
  Installed executable devtools.
  Warning: Executable "devtools" runs "bin\devtools.dart", which was not found in devtools.

I already turned off my antivira.

The project structure also shows this issue:
Library Dart Packages has broken classes paths:   C:\Users\annaH\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\google_fonts-2.1.0\lib   C:\Users\annaH\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\path_provider_macos-2.0.0\lib [Fix]

The Fix option does not work

I am really appreciative of any help or tipps on how to fix this issue :) !!
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try
dart pub global activate devtools